# Mi metodo devuelve una salida inesperada

Tags: java

Tengo tres clases (`Leer`,`Prueba` y `Cadena`). Desde la clase `Leer` introduzco una cadena por teclado, desde la clase `Prueba` es donde se encuentra el `Main` y 
en la clase `Cadena` tengo un método que devuelve un `entero`.

El objetivo de mi código consiste en introducir una frase y una palabra y ver cuantas veces se repite la palabra introducida en la frase.

**Ejemplo**

```java
String frase = "Hola que tal Hola";
String palabra = "Hola";
```

La salida esperada debería ser `int contador = 2`

En mi código realizo bucles `for` hallando la longitud de la cadena `length()` y separando con `charAt()`, pero coloco el contador y mi salida no me devuelve nada.

**Clase Leer**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Leer {

    public static String ReadString() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una cadena");
        String cadena = sc.nextLine();

        return cadena;

    }
```

**Clase Prueba**

```
public class Prueba5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(Cadena.ContarPalabra());

    }

}
```

**Clase Cadena**

```
public class Cadena {

    public static int ContarPalabra() {

        int contador = 0; // Contador de veces que sale la palabra repetida 
        String cadena = Leer.ReadString();// Frase introducida por teclado 
        String palabra = " ";
        String mipalabra = Leer.ReadString();// Palabra introducida por teclado

        cadena = cadena + " ";

        for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++) {

            palabra = palabra + cadena.charAt(i);

            if(cadena.charAt(i)==' ') {

                if(mipalabra.equals(palabra)) {

                  contador++;

                }

            }

            palabra = "";

        }

        return contador;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de tomar la cadena, adicional pondría un `toLowerCase()` para evitar que no funcione bien cuando una palabra tenga un una mayúscula y por ello no la reconozca:

```java
String cadena = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Así **hola** podrá ser comparado con **Hola**, por ejemplo.

---

**Ahora bien, en la parte del `for`, al recorrer la frase estás recorriendo carácter por carácter, cuando deberías de recorrer palabra por palabra.**

```java
int contador = 0; // Contador de veces que sale la palabra repetida 
String cadena = Leer.ReadString();// Frase introducida por teclado 
String[] cadenaFragmentada = cadena.split(" "); //separa palabra por palabra
String mipalabra = Leer.ReadString();// Palabra introducida por teclado
for (int i = 0; i < cadenaFragmentada.length; i++) {     
     if(cadenaFragmentada[i].equals(mipalabra)){
         contador++;
     }     
}
return contador;
```

Lo anterior he eliminado la variable `palabra` y en su lugar he creado un `array` de tipo `String`, llamado `cadenaFragmentada`, el cual guarda palabra por palabra de la frase.

Con `split()`, he separado la frase palabra por palabra por cada espacio que esta contenga, `cadena.split(" ")`.

Por último recorro el `array` `cadenaFragmentada` y comparo cada una de las posiciones con la palabra introducida por teclado.

**RESULTADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *"Ahora bien, en la parte del for, al recorrer la frase estás recorriendo carácter por carácter, cuando deberías de recorrer palabra por palabra."* Da lo mismo si lo recorres palabra por palabra o caracter por caracter, no tiene nada que ver con el error del OP. La razón es porqué ha puesto en un lugar inadecuado la expresión de concatenación y adicionalmente, agregó la inicialización del puntero implícito `palabra` afuera del `if` cuando en realidad debería estar adentro.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo y donde creo que puede estar el problema es el if:

```
if(cadena.charAt(i)==' ') {
```

creo de deberia ser

```
if(cadena.charAt(i)!=' ') {
```

Sino no entra hasta el final y por tanto no cuenta nada

ademas estoy viendo que reseteas "palabra" en cada iteración,
la variable palabra solo debería reiniciarse en caso de entrar en

```
    if(mipalabra.equals(palabra)) {
      contador++;
      palabra = "";
    }
```

espero que sea eso

Comment: Si cambias la condición de esa forma, en cada iteración estarías comparando los objetos cuando en realidad no debería ser así, por lo tanto, la restricción está bien sin el operador de `!=`. Adicionalmente, si agregas el código `palabra = "";` adentro del `if`, nunca se estaría actualizando palabra por palabra, es decir, se quedará con la palabra anterior si es que la condición nunca llegara a cumplirse. La inicialización debería estar afuera del `if`.